# Probability Need help understanding how to work problem out

Tags: probability-distributions

What number would complete this probability distribution?  And could you explain how, I am new to this and my textbook isn't helping.

x     3    7    11

---

P(X)0.38  0.29  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** There are three possible outcomes, $3$, $7$, and $11$. The sum of the probabilities of these three outcomes is $1$.

Comment: I still don't get it if the 3 is 0.38, and the 7 is 0.29 the how did they get these numbers so I can find the missing number for 11 which is ?.  Hope this makes since I am just lost.

Comment: How they got the numbers is not important, maybe it was by doing a certain experiment many times. The point is that if you have a list of all the possible outcomes, their probabilities must add up to $1$. So if $p$ is the unknown probability that the result is $11$, then $0.38+0.29+p=1$. From this you can easily find $p$.

Comment: Thank you I see now. Was trying to hard.

Comment: You are welcome. There was nothing special about the numbers $0.38$ and $0.29$.